# UITableViewCell Selected Background Color on DidSelectRow

Tags: swift

I want to change the background when I select the table. Right now, when I select two tables, the background changes to 2. I just want to change the background of the last table I chose. So just change the background of one table, not two. Change the background of the last painting I chose.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     if tableView == self.tableView1 {
        let cell:DeviceTableViewCell2 = tableView1.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell2
  cell.selectionStyle = .none

            cell.backgroundColor = GradientColor(UIGradientStyle.diagonal, frame: self.view.frame, colors: [UIColor.flatPowderBlueDark, UIColor.flatSand])

        }
        if tableView == self.tableView2 {
            let cell:DeviceTableViewCell2 = tableView2.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdNew, for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell2
 cell.selectionStyle = .none

                cell.backgroundColor = GradientColor(UIGradientStyle.diagonal, frame: self.view.frame, colors: [UIColor.flatPowderBlueDark, UIColor.flatSand])

            }
  if tableView == self.tableView3 {
                let cell:DeviceTableViewCell2 = tableView3.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdNew2, for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell2
cell.selectionStyle = .none


                cell.backgroundColor = GradientColor(UIGradientStyle.diagonal, frame: self.view.frame, colors: [UIColor.flatPowderBlueDark, UIColor.flatSand])
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if tableView == self.tableView1 {
let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView1.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
                    selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatGray
}
 if tableView == self.tableView2 {
 let selectedCell2:UITableViewCell = tableView2.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
                        selectedCell2.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatGray
                    }
if tableView == self.tableView3 {
 let selectedCell3:UITableViewCell = tableView3.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
                        selectedCell3.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatGray
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not change the `backgroundColor` of the `contentView` or of the cell itself, use the `selectedBackgroundView` instead:

```
 cell.backgroundView = UIView()
 cell.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = // your color when not selected

 cell.selectedBackgroundView = UIView()
 cell.selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = // your color when selected
```

After this initial setup, there is no need to change anything. Everything will work automatically.

Do not set `cell.selectionStyle = .none` because that will disable selection completely.

Comment: I want the selected table to remain completely that color. I always want that color left after I choose it. But only one painting.

Comment: @BerkooBek A cell will be kept selected and it will keep its selected background color until you deselect it. You might want to manually deselect all rows you don't want to keep selected. You can always access selected index paths in other tables and call `deselectRow(at:, animated:)` on all of them.